# Custom spring initializr instance - adding custom java class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-starter, spring-initializr

I am trying to create my own instance of spring initializr as described in https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/current/reference/html/#create-instance. My need is to add custom java classes in the generated project (Other than the default @SpringBootApplication class). I am not able to figure out how to do that. Not finding any examples anywhere as well. If someone can guide me on how to do that would be helpful.

Comment: If your custom classes could be located through some artifact on Maven Central Repository, you can add them manually (example is on [same tutorial page](https://docs.spring.io/initializr/docs/current/reference/html/#create-instance-dependencies)). Otherwise they should be added manually to generated Maven pom.xml

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko thanks. Can you please specify the section # for the example you are referring to? Just to clarify, I need to add lets say my own CustomJavaClass.java file in the generated folder structure. This class is not a third party library class but my own custom one

Comment: `#create-instance-dependencies`